# Azure AD B2C custom policy with multiple domains in single federated tenant

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using [Home realm discovery mordern](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/home-realm-discovery-modern/policy/SignIn_smart_HRD.xml) policy. I am using Custom policies to log in with multiple azure ad tenants. now I have a tenant with more than one domain. So I need to understand that how can I provide multiple ClaimValueOnWhichToEnable metadata in the technical profile of this policy.

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar situation and i have added multiple `<ClaimsProvider>` tags with  **`<Item Key="ClaimValueOnWhichToEnable">domain.com</Item>`** for each domain with the same tenant details and it works as exepected.